# Are Tor network nodes/relays proxies? If not, what is the difference?

Tags: relays, proxy, node

I would like to know if there is any difference between the concept of "proxy" and the nodes (also known as relays) that make up the Tor network. I mean: Are the nodes proxies themselves? If not, what's the difference?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way:

Nodes are **other computers** that bounce your internet connection all over the world

A proxy is the **service** that your local copy of Tor or Tor Browser provides that you use to access the Tor network.

The proxy is *your* door to Tor.  The node are the stops along the way from you to your destination.

If you want to help the Tor network, you can create your own Node, that is, you can add another stop for other people to use. This strengthens the Tor network by making it bigger and more secure. The local door that you use (the proxy) is only on your computer.

Comment: 1/2 The point is that I am reading a 1996 document on Onion Routing ("Hiding Routing Information"). This document describes a connection between two parts by means of a virtual circuit, very similar to the one Tor is currently using. 

In the illustration of this circuit (which I have attached in the message above), the first and last node (what we now know as entry guard- and exit node) are described as "Proxy/Routing Nodes", while intermediate nodes are only described as "intermediate routing nodes".

Comment: 2/2 Does this name hold up in the current Tor circuits? The entry guard and the exit node are "Proxy/Routing Nodes", while the intermediate node is just an "intermediate routing node"? What do you think?